How to handle Google Play subscription status when a user is signed in using Firebase email/password
I've followed the documentation on Google Play Billing library for Android and everything seems to work fine. I'm using billing lab to test it. Then I thought to myself, what would happen if I subscribe while being signed in to one Firebase account, and then switch to another. I found out that the user is still marked as subscribed. Here's how i get this status:
billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(params) { billingResult, purchases ->
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                purchases.any { it.purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED && it.isAcknowledged }
            }
        }

I understand that the reason it happens is because subscriptions are tied to Google accounts. But is there a way to differentiate subscriptions between Firebase accounts?
EDIT:
The problem is that my app uses firestore to store limits (cover letter generations per day), and those limits depend on whether or not a user is subscribed. So in the current setting a person could just create a bunch of firebase accounts and bankrupt me.

No.  Google Play doesn't recognize Firebase accounts for the purpose of billing.  As you've mentioned, "subscriptions are tied to Google accounts". Everyone is required to use a Google account on their Android device to sign in to the Play store and manage billing information, regardless of any other applications that might or might not be installed.

Thank you. The problem is that my app uses firestore to store limits (cover letter generations per day), and those limits depend on whether or not a user is subscribed. So in the current setting a person could just create a bunch of firebase accounts and bankrupt me.

Sure, you might want to look into ways of defending yourself against that if you think it will be a problem. But the answer to your question still stands as "no".  If you have a new question, please post it separately.
